# Echo tag value from HTML file in PHP file

Tags: php, html

I have this html file with this tag:

**fileHTML.html**

```
<input type="hidden" id="inputID" value="test">
```

Is it possible to echo the tag value (ie: "test") in an external PHP file ?
This is where I am now.

**filePHP.php**

```
<?php                  
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTMLFile("fileHTML.html");
  // echo the value in the input tag from $doc
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. For simplicity reasons I load the HTML from a string.

You first have to get the element and then the attribute value (which is called "value" in your example too).

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<input type="hidden" id="inputID" value="test">');
  
$element = $doc->getElementById('inputID');
var_dump($element->getAttribute('value')); // outputs: string(4) "test"
```